# Is BMC PRO MACHINE SLC01 2009 compatible with Ultegra Di2?

Tags: shimano-di2

Currently I have Ultegra 6800, but I want to upgrade it with Ultegra Di2. My frame (BMC PRO MACHINE SLC01 2009) compatible with Di2?

Comment: In theory, yes, although you picked an expensive way to upgrade. The fly in thei' ointment could be internal /external cable routing, might also need to compromise on where you house the battery. I've kinda decided to do this upgrade myself (one day), except when I go for it, I'll replace the whole bike.

Comment: Thanks! I also want to do it myself. What do you mean by replacing the whole bike? Do you mean there is a lot of work?

Comment: Given that you have 6800 already, it might even be less work than a normal groupset replacement - you may get away with replacing just derailleurs and shifters (but you should check this). My comment above was largely based on expense - I reckon a good deal on a whole new bike would not be a lot more than buying a new DI2 group. Plus the new frame will have been designed with DI2 in mind (in terms of keeping cables out of the way)